# Attempting to find the equivalence class of 5.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ define $a \sim b$ if $a - b \in \mathbb{Z}$

How would you find the equivalence class of 5.
In other words what I'm trying to describe is the set $[5]$ = {$y : 5 \sim y$}. And $[5]$ is just the name of the set.

Comment: You show how would one go to prove the relation is an equivalence one. How does this serve us to **find** $\;[5]\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The answers to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543667/prove-that-sim-defines-an-equivalence-relation-on-mathbbz) contain a description of the equivalence classes:

> $a \sim b$ iff $a$ and $b$ have the same fractional part.

The fractional part of $5$ is $0$. Which other real numbers have zero fractional part?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: By definition $[5]=\{x\in\Bbb R:5\sim x\}=\{x\in\Bbb R:5-x\in\Bbb Z\}$. $5-x\in\Bbb Z$ if and only if $5-x$ is an integer, i.e., there is an $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $5-x=n$. By elementary algebra this is equivalent to saying that $x=5-n$ for some integer $n$, so $[5]=\{5-n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$. What real numbers can be written in the form $5-n$ for some integer $n$? This set has a very simple description.

Comment: So would the real numbers be 0,1,2,3,4?

Comment: @micheal: That would be the case if $[5]$ were $\{x\in\Bbb R:5-x\in\Bbb Z^+\}$, but $\Bbb Z$ is the set of **all** integers, positive, negative, and zero. For example, $5-7=-2$, and $-2\in\Bbb Z$, so $7\in[5]$. So what all is in $[5]$?

Comment: Oh, so it would be all numbers -infinity to 5. Or would it be -infinity to infinity since the set includes negatives and such.

Comment: @micheal: The latter: **every** integer is $5-n$ for some integer $n$. $100$ is $5-(-95)$; $-100$ is $5-105$; and you can easily see that every integer can be written in this way. Thus, $[5]=\Bbb Z$. Similarly, $[n]=\Bbb Z$ no matter what integer $n$ is.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So if on the other hand let's say you were the trying to find the equivalence class of something like [3.2]. Would the class be empty then since 3.2 is not an integer?

Comment: @micheal: It couldn’t possibly be empty: no matter what equivalence relation you’re talking about, an object is always a member of its own equivalence class, because by definition every equivalence relation is reflexive. $[3.2]$ is the set of all real numbers that differ from $3.2$ by an integer. Some of these numbers are $5.2,1.2,0.2,-1.8$, and $-3.8$. For instance, $-3.8=3.2-7$.