# Proving that $aRb \iff a^2-b^2=a-b$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Could you help me with that, I don't know how to prove if the relation is an equivalence and the class of 5?

On the set of integers, the relationship is defined by $aRb \iff a^2-b^2=a-b$.  Find out if it is an equivalence relation and where appropriate, find the equivalence class of 5.

Comment: Assuming that $a \neq b$ that is.

Comment: You may also notice that $a^2-b^2=a-b$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $(a-b)(a+b)=a-b$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $a=b$ $\lor$ $a+b=1$. (Although it probably does not simplify things.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the relation is clearly reflexive since $a^2 - a^2 = 0 = a - a$ for any integer $a$.

Second, the equation $a^2 - b^2 = a - b$ is symmetric since switching $a$ and $b$ introduces negative signs on both sides.  More precisely, if $a^2 - b^2 = a - b$ then $b^2 - a^2 = -(a^2 - b^2) = -(a - b)= b-a$.

Is it transitive?  Suppose that $a^2 - b^2 = a - b$ and $b^2 - c^2 = b - c$.  Then $a^2 - c^2 = a^2 - b^2 + b^2 - c^2 = (a^2 - b^2) + (b^2 - c^2) = (a-b) + (b - c) = a - c$, so indeed it is transitive.

To find the equivalence class of $5$ we need to find all integers $a$ such that $a^2 - 5^2 = a - 5$ which is equivalent to $0=a^2 - a - 20=(a + 4)(a-5)$, so we see that $a = -4$ or $a = 5$.  Hence the equivalence class of $5$ consists of $\{ -4, 5\}$.

Comment: Very nicely delivered!

Answer (score 7):

$a R b$ iff $f(a)=f(b)$, where $f(x)=x^2-x$. Since equality is an equivalence relation, so is $R$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/92277/589 and http://math.stackexchange.com/a/543673/589.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to solve the equation: $$a^2-b^2=a-b$$

The decision will then be:

$$a=\frac{-k+n+1}{2}$$

$$b=\frac{k-n+1}{2}$$

$k,n$ - integers different parity. Any sign.